# Dynamically Javascript to increase the value of checkbox

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble increasing the value of the checkbox automatically which is sitting inside a table. So, in short, In my HTML table, I have text boxes and a checkbox present as a row(default 5 rows are shows when the webpage is loaded). I have a button that calls below javascript to automatically clone a row, if anytime end-user wants to add more rows to this existing default 5 rows HTML table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cloneRow() {
      var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
      var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
      var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
      clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
      table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    }

// This function deletes a row when clicked on the button
function deleteRow(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}
```

Now in my HTML, the checkbox looks like this :
PS: The value "3" indicates rows number, so here in this example this checkbox is located in 3rd rows.

```
<tr id="rowToClone">
        <td id="Transportation_Type">
            <select id="Transportation_Type" onChange="checkOption(this)" name="transportation_type">
                {% for type in transportation_type %}
                <option value="{{ type.type }}">{{ type.type }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="License_Plate" name="License_Plate" placeholder="Optional" style="text-align:center;" disabled></td>
        <td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Electric" value="3"/></td>
        <td id="Number of days per week" >
            <select name="DaysPerWeek">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="DistanceInKm" style="text-align:center;" ></td>
        <td><button class="button is-danger "  onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete Row</button></td>
    </tr>
```

So now my question is when clicking the clone button, how a new row will get the next value in the checkbox?

Let's say the end-user clicks a one-time `clone button`, then the checkbox along with others will be clone but only the value of checkbox should be "6" automatically.

Comment: You should check the id of the elements in your DOM because ids are for identification and there should not be elements with the same id

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of rows in the table. Add 1 to that to get the appropriate value for the checkbox.

```js
function cloneRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
  var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
  clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
  var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr").length;
  clone.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").value = rows+1;
  table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
```

If there's a header row in the table that shouldn't be counted, don't add 1.

Comment: this is exactly what I expected, Thanks. However, It also clones the values selected as well. let's say I have chosen the values in my html table, now I click the clonebutton, this replicates the rows with checkbox value as row+1 but it at the same time copies the filled-in values from the textboxes. Is it possible to clone the rows but without filledin values to copied over other than the checkbox? It should clone empty set of rows .

Comment: you should clone a template, not one of the rows that are in use.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not great at JS, could you assist me to create one or help me to read and proceed?

Comment: Use the `<template>` tag, and put `rowToClone` in there, not in the real ltable.